# SEDE graphs displaying nothing after today's update

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Stack Exchange [tweeted today about a SEDE update](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/557539801797505024)

After this update, the "graph" view of the SEDE seems broken. [It displays absolutely nothing](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Apparently*

```
// Time mode was moved to a plug-in in 0.8, and since so many people use it
// we'll add an especially friendly reminder to make sure they included it.
```

Which is obviously news to me, as it seems I didn't test the upgrade with dates. I'm giving myself a -1 for incomplete testing, and giving you [a fix](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/56), pending a pull and redeploy.

Comment: I just read your MSE profile: *"I've also been known to occasionally break (and sometimes fix!) the Data Explorer"* <--- this explains everything!

Comment: I'd prefer it to be more about fixing, but that doesn't seem to be going so well for me today (cleaning up my own messes notwithstanding). :P

Comment: Admit it, you did that on purpose so that you can gain some shiny rep! ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Let's go with that, since it's far less embarrassing than the reality.

Comment: Anyway let's hope Nick will give this priority, remember it once took over half year to pull and redeploy the code. People would be miserable without graphs! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hey, he's [on top of it](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/557689930571587584)!